# Have any vb applications migrated to delphi?

Tags: vb.net, delphi, vb6, vb6-migration

I would like to hear of the experiences of classic vb developers who migrated their applications to delphi rather than vb.net. How has it worked out? Are you glad or sorry that you didn't move to vb.net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not really a vb developer but rather a Delphi developer who was forced to maintain some vb apps for a while. I tried to migrate one vb app to vb.net and after that experience I never tried it again. I successfully migrated several vb apps to Delphi. It wasn't easy and it became a pain in the lower back to find native Delphi replacements for some of the OCXes that had been used (I will never again rely on a third party library for which I do not have the source code.), but it worked out OK.

But as said above: I am an experienced Delphi developer, so I didn't have to learn Delphi at the same time as migrating a vb app. That certainly made it much easier.

Comment: Can you give me some idea of the size of these apps and the time taken to migrate?

Comment: This was quite a while ago, so I might not remember correctly:

The one I tried to migrate to vb.net had a few thousand lines of code but used several OCXes. I gave up on it after about 3 days.

One I successfully migrated to Delphi had nearly a 100000 loc and it took me about a week.

Comment: 100K lines in a week is incredibly quick!

Comment: This might help as well:
http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/vb2delphi_migration.html

Comment: Those 100K lines included all the internal (existing) libraries I was using to speed up the progress. Also, the original vb code was spaghetti code of the finest, so I got away with throwing a lot of stuff into the bin. (as said above: Memory is hazy about this issue, I don't want to rememember vb)

Answer (score 3):

I just spotted this on [DelphiFeeds](http://www.delphifeeds.com/):

**[Delphi for Visual Basic developers](http://delphi.about.com/od/beginners/a/vb2delphi.htm)**
*Help to migrate VB applications (knowledge and skills) to Delphi*

Answer (score 2):

I had a good friend who moved from Classic VB to Delphi a while ago (back before .NET).  He was really happy with the move.

The company he worked for made applications in VB, and they put together a special team (2 developers) to create Active X controls in Delphi for the rest of the company to use.  Additionally, when there was something that they couldn't do in VB then the Delphi team would do it.  That was when he was introduced to Delphi.

He said it didn't take long before the Delphi team could prototype applications in Delphi faster then the rest of the development group (he never said how large, but way more then two) could.  The company never made the switch to Delphi from VB because someone was under the impression the VB was a better solution despite the evidence that Delphi was more powerful and faster.

Comment: I don't need persuading that Delphi is the cat's pyjamas, bees knees and dog's bollix combined, I wann know how hard it is to migrate ;)

Comment: Yeah, I think I started off and got distracted, in the end forgetting to answer your question.  Now I don't even remember what the point was.  sorry about that. . .

Answer (score 2):

A few years are I was working with another student on our placement year. We worked for a very large manufacturing company. One of his projects was to create a classic VB app to interface with multiple cameras on a production line and analyse the data in real time. In classic VB this was a shambles - it took on average 1.5 minutes to process a single frame from a single camera (7 cameras at 24 fps) there was no that he could optimise it.

He eventually took the plunge in to Delphi and re-written that app and works fantastically. I've recently been in contact with a few friends who still work there and his app is been running smoothly for 3 years now.

Answer (score 1):

I've worked in both VB and Delphi, and Delphi is (IMO) *much* less frustrating/limiting.  You should be able to use ActiveX / OCX controls as needed (though I agree w/other comments re: avoiding there where you can, and being sure ot have full source code).  Apps we've migrated from VB to Delphi (two) have gone well.

Comment: Can you give me some idea of the size of these apps and the time and number of developers taken to migrate? Also your prior experience in both languages..oh and what did you have for breakfast!

Comment: Egg sandwich. ;-)

They were relatively small apps -- 1 or 2 developers, over a few months; but in general, we found Delphi just a lot "smarter" in terms of how it was structured and "thought" (truly object-oriented, being the main difference, and VB's lack of that the main frustration/annoyance).

Comment: thanks, that sounds like the sort of time frame i was thinking of

Answer (score 0):

I did try in two  instance to migrate from VB to Delphi but unfortunately I had to abort midway in one app as it used a lot of third party ActiveX (most from ComponentOne and a few from CodeJoke). We had to abort midway as we could not find any VCL components having equivalent functionality to the ActiveX used in the project.

It was a nightmare for us. Thank god we aborted midway and switched to C#. It was unbelievable that we could get all the features in .NET component to the ditto!

The app we managed to convert, went well off but we had to get rid of a few features that we had implemented in the original  software as they required more work in Delphi.